# What is the HTML entity name for an Indian rupee

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities

I know that we can use the entity numbers `&#x20b9;` and `&#8377;` to display an Indian rupee symbol(₹). But as the pound has entity name `&pound;`, the yen has `&yen;`, is there any special name like `&rupee;` to be used to display this symbol?

I came to know that there's none, can anyone suggest how can we apply to the w3 community to add that specific character to the list and apply it's usage

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Clive. But I can't find rupee there!

Comment: You can probably assume there isn’t one in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, there is no process for getting a new named reference in HTML.  That means, you won't get `&rupee;` or `&emoji-train;` or similar.

HTML5 entity names are all listed at https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#named-character-references

They are derived from the XML entity names https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/

The preferred way of referencing characters is using their decimal or hexidecimal reference. In this case `&#8377;` or `&#x20B9;`.

This is because an older browser may not know what to do with `&rupee;` - but will always know how to look up a numeric reference in a font table.

The easiest way is just to paste in the `₹` symbol directly.

Answer (score 0):

So, found out from this link: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/indian-rupee-sign/

There's still no html entity name for the Indian rupee symbol(₹) but there are only unicode, hex code, html code and css code as mentioned on the above given link:

```
UNICODE  U+020B9
HEX CODE &#x20B9;
HTML CODE  &#8377;
CSS CODE   \20B9
```

But I still hope that it would soon be added. As Indian rupee symbol is being extensively used!